# Test two boolean values with AND operator in Perl

Tags: perl, boolean-expression

I want to test two boolean values in Perl.
In case both are 0 do x, in case not do y.
For example:
$var1 = 0; false in Perl
$var2 = 0; false in Perl

```
if($var1==0 && var2==0)
{
  x //both are false
}
else
{
 y //both are true
}
```

Comment: Are you wanting to do y only if both conditions are true or whenever one condition is true?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```perl
if ( $var1 && $var2 ) {
   # Both are true.
}
elsif ( !$var1 && !$var2 ) {
   # Both are false.
}
```

or

```perl
if ( !( $var1 xor $var2 ) ) {
   # Both are true or both are false.
   if ( $var1 ) {
      # Both are true.
   } else {
      # Both are false.
   }
}
```

or

```perl
if ( $var1 ) { 
   if ( $var2 ) {
      # Both are true.
   }
} else {
   if ( !$var2 ) {
      # Both are false.
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So … assuming you want y only when both $var1 and $var2 are true:

```
 if (!$var1 and !$var2) {
    # do x
  } elsif ($var1 and $var2) {
     # do y
  }
```

But there TIMTOWTDI. Because Perl.